# Difficulty in deleting characters near slashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function formatDate(input) {
  // Remove non-numeric characters from the input
  let numericValue = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

  // Add a slash immediately after the 2nd character
  if (numericValue.length > 1 && numericValue.charAt(2) !== '/') {
    numericValue = numericValue.slice(0, 2) + '/' + numericValue.slice(2);
  }

  // Add a slash immediately after the 5th character
  if (numericValue.length > 4 && numericValue.charAt(5) !== '/') {
    numericValue = numericValue.slice(0, 5) + '/' + numericValue.slice(5);
  }

  input.value = numericValue;
}
```

The provided formatDate function is designed to format a date input by adding slashes (/) immediately at specific positions. The function removes non-numeric characters from the input and then inserts slashes after the 2nd and 5th characters. However, an issue arises when users attempt to delete characters from right to left within the input field.

When a user tries to delete characters near the slashes, the deletion stops at the slash, requiring them to manually delete each character. For example, if the date is "05/18/2023" and the user wants to delete the "18" portion, the cursor will stop at the slash after "2".

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue and allow users to delete characters smoothly, including those near the slashes or is there any other way to do my requirement (add slashes automatically for the input after the second and 5th character)

Comment: fwiw, what you're trying to achieve here is usually referred to as "input masking". It can be...hard. Consider a library like `iMaskJs` https://imask.js.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" maxlength="10">
```

```
const inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');//get your input field

inputField.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (!/^([0-9])$/.test(e.key)) {//check if the key is number
        return e.preventDefault();
    }
});

inputField.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    let temp = this.value.split("/").join(""), valLength = this.value.length;
    if (this.value.length > 5) {
        this.value = temp.slice(0, 2) + '/' + temp.slice(2, 4) + '/' + temp.slice(4);
    } else if (this.value.length > 2) {
        this.value = temp.slice(0, 2) + '/' + temp.slice(2);
    }
});
```

Please note that if the user is trying to delete any character before slash for example in date `12/09/2002` if the user is trying to delete any character from `0` to `5` then the cursor will jump to the last position and also the user cannot delete the `/` by moving the cursor after it, if there exists other numbers after the cursor. So the best practice would be to delete and add numbers from last only.

Comment: I want to have a slash immediately after adding the character. as an example after adding the second character slash should be added. format (DD/MM/YYYY)